# Optimizing speed of plotting municipal/regional data on a map in R

Tags: r, maps, r-sp

I am looking at plotting data for regions in a country. I need to do that for many datasets (but on the same country). I have a working method, which I have built on the following code http://biblogg.no/2015/05/18/building-a-map-of-norway-in-r/ in the section called "Building Maps in R using the ‘sp’ Package (Lattice Plot)". This works fine and is pretty neat. The method used the SP packages and works with Spatial Polygons.

However, it is extremely slow, given how little it does (Excel does the same in a tenth of the time). This leads me to wonder whether there is a simpler method, when my dataset for each graph only contains an integer per region. I have previously with with the "map_data" function for country mapping, but that doesn't seem to work for regions in all countries

Edit:posting the data used

```
norway2 <- readOGR(dsn="/Users/isa/Documents/Courses/Johns Hopkins/RKart_Norge/NOR_adm" ,
               layer="NOR_adm2")
# We take a look at the data
norway2_data <- norway2@data
str(norway2_data); head(norway2_data)

# We create a dataframe for the churn rate per regions
d <- c( "Akershus" , "Aust-Agder", "Buskerud", "Finnmark",  "Hedmark" ,  "Hordaland",  "Møre og Romsdal" , "Nord-Trøndelag" ,   "Nordland" ,  "Oppland", "Oslo", "Ãstfold", "Rogaland",  "Sogn og Fjordane",  "Sør-Trøndelag",  "Telemark",  "Troms", "Vest-Agder" , "Vestfold" )
e <- c(1.0, 1.1, 1.5, 1.55, 2.9, 3.12, 3.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.8, 5.1, 5.3, 5.5, 5.56, 7.9, 8.3, 11, 5.6, 6.1)
name3 <- c("NAME_1", "Churn"); dt2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(d, e),     stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
dt2$e <- as.numeric(dt2$e); colnames(dt2) <- name3; churn <- dt2
# We plot the Norwegian regions using the unionSpatialPolygons function from the 'maptools' package
IDs <- norway2_data$ID_1
# We merge Polygons
norway3_new <- unionSpatialPolygons(norway2, IDs)
# We build the new SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with the churn rate
norway4_new <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(norway3_new, churn) 

# Then you can use spplot to visualize the Norwegian regions with their respective churn rate
# We define the color palette
pal2 <- colorRampPalette(c("white", "red"))
# Remove the plot frame
trellis.par.set(axis.line=list(col=NA))
# Plot the regions with Lattice
spplot(norway4_new, "Churn", main="Churn Rate per Norwegian Region (Fylke)", 
   lwd=.4, col="white", col.regions=pal2(19), colorkey = FALSE, bty="n")
```

Comment: can u post sample data here and what kind of plotting u r getting from lattice? can u add any samples here?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have posted the code (which includes some sample data from Norway). The plot is exactly as seen on the link

Comment: The tutorial you following is old and the link for the shapefile is no longer available. But  the best way to render faster is to have a spatial polygon object with only the necessary amount of details to generate your map. You can reduce the number of vertices using rgeos:gSimplify. Also consider the use of ggplot2:geom_map if your more interested in generating maps than performing spatial analysis.